# Read Configuration values in Extension class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working on a .net core project. and have created a simple extension class for my logger method.something like below.

```
public static class LogExtension
{
   public static void Log(this ILogger Log,string otherparameters)
   {
       //want to read configuration value here from settings.
   }

}
```

As mentioned above, I am looking to read configuration value from appsetting here.

As normally with other classes, I am aware about using IConfiguration interface and having it injected as dependency in classes.

However not able to find way to do the same in Static class . Is there a nice way to do this rather than a workout of creating a static property in startup class and reading from there.

Comment: Unless those values are somehow resolved from the container, eventually you're going to end up with some untestable dependency. And if those values are specific to any implementation of `ILogger`, that's a problem too. The implementation of `ILogger` should already have whatever configuration values it needs injected into it.

Comment: @ScottHannen do you mean the extension method of the Ilogger should have parameter of the configuration value ? That then forces me to have the configuration value in every controller and pass it with every log call which I want to avoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your logging extension looks like this:

```
public static class LogExtension
{
   public static void Log(this ILogger Log, Exception ex) // as an example
   {
       // read from configuration settings here
   }
}
```

...then every method anywhere in your code that uses this will become dependent on that call to get configuration settings. That somewhat defeats the purpose of using dependency injection, since now all of your code will be coupled to whatever provides that setting.

If you write a unit test for a class that depends on `ILogger`, the logger itself is an abstraction, but the extension method won't be. Whatever is inside that extension method, your code is coupled to it. You can't solve that problem by assigning values to static properties. It just moves the problem around. You still wouldn't be able to write unit tests without someone accounting for those static properties you need.

That will make writing unit tests very difficult.

You're already using dependency injection, so instead, continue to follow that pattern. Whatever configuration values your logger needs, inject them into your logger. For example,

```
public class Logger : ILogger
{
    private readonly ILoggingSettings _settings;

    public Logger(ILoggingSettings settings)
    {
        _settings = setting;
    }
}
```

Then, just as you register an implementation of `ILogger` at startup, register an implementation of `ILoggingSettings` too. (If it's just some properties read from configuration you don't really need an interface - it could just be a class, `LoggingSettings`.) Now whatever configuration settings the logger needs are hidden inside of it, and the rest of your code doesn't need to deal with it.

For clarity, that's the step where you're looking at `IConfiguration`. It's all at startup. You would read values from `IConfiguration` to populate `LoggingSettings`.

Your question doesn't specify that you're creating your own `ILogger` implementation. Maybe you're using something existing, like `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`, and you want the settings to determine how that logging behaves. In that case, you could do something like this:

Create your own `ILogger` interface with the methods that you want, and have the implementation of it wrap Microsoft's interface. (There's some benefit to writing your own logging interface. It doesn't stop you from using it to wrap any other logging framework.)

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void LogException(Exception ex, string message);
}

public class Logger : ILogger
{
    private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger _innerLogger;
    private readonly LoggingSettings _settings;

    public Logger(
        Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger innerLogger,
        LoggingSettings settings
    )
    {
        _innerLogger = innerLogger;
        _settings = settings;
    }

    public void LogException(Exception ex, string message)
    {
        if (_settings.ShouldILogThis)
        {
            _innerLogger.LogError(ex, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Now your classes depend on this `ILogger` interface. They have no idea that when they call `LogException`, the implementation of `ILogger` is checking some settings, deciding what to do, and then calling a completely different logging implementation. All of that complexity is hidden behind the `ILogger` interface.

What if one day you don't need those settings? Or what if you want to use a different logging framework? Now you won't have to modify code all over the place. You'll just change the implementation of `ILogger`, and the rest of your code won't know the difference. That realistic. It's common for us to write stuff like this and then realize later that we don't need it.

Your classes are also easy to test because you can easily supply a mock of `ILogger` that does something specific or nothing at all. You won't have to worry about supplying it with configuration values in a unit test.

---

A key concept is *managing complexity*. Whatever complexity we need is what we need. If we need to read from configuration settings, then we need to do that. We can't make it go away.

What we can do is decide where to put it. So the idea is that our classes deal with simple abstractions like `ILogger`, and all of that complexity goes into the implementation of the abstraction and how we compose it at startup. We're *containing* that complexity, keeping it from leaking out into other classes.

Comment: Only issue i face with this solution for me is , how do i ensure that this implementation is called from other static classes which need logging because they themselves also do not have dependency injection added for my custom Logger class implementation. do you have suggestions?

Comment: One way is to pass the `ILogger` as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to access `IConfiguration` from a static class, nor should you. Any extensions you're making to `ILogger` should not have dependencies on unrelated things like `IConfiguration`. If you need a configuration value in one of the extension methods, for some reason, then you should pass in the value as a parameter, and resolve the configuration from whatever is calling this extension method.

As far as the actual logger configuration goes, the place for that is in `Startup.ConfigureServices` or in `Program`, by adding a `ConfigueLogging` block to the builder. `ILogger` is intentionally an abstraction, and should remain that way.